# Convert dictionary of nested lists into DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, nested-lists

I have a dictionary of nested lists

```
d = {'IBGB100': [RealTimeBar(time=datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 19, 17, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), open_=7169.42, high=7169.67, low=7169.42, close=7169.42, volume=-1, wap=-1.0, count=-1),
                 RealTimeBar(time=datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 19, 17, 5, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), open_=7169.42, high=7169.42, low=7168.92, close=7168.92, volume=-1, wap=-1.0, count=-1)],
      'IBEU50': [RealTimeBar(time=datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 19, 17, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), open_=3262.455, high=3262.455, low=3262.455, close=3262.455, volume=-1, wap=-1.0, count=-1),
                 RealTimeBar(time=datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 19, 17, 5, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), open_=3262.455, high=3262.455, low=3262.455, close=3262.455, volume=-1, wap=-1.0, count=-1)],
      'IBDE30': [RealTimeBar(time=datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 19, 17, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), open_=11417.15, high=11417.655, low=11416.9, close=11416.9, volume=-1, wap=-1.0, count=-1),
                 RealTimeBar(time=datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 19, 17, 5, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), open_=11416.9, high=11416.905, low=11416.15, close=11416.65, volume=-1, wap=-1.0, count=-1)]}
```

I am trying to convert into a DataFrame in this format

```
instrument   datetime                open       high        low        close    volume    wap    count
'IBGB100'    2019, 2, 21, 19, 17,    7169.42    7169.67     7169.42    7169.42   -1       -1.0   -1
             2019, 2, 21, 19, 17, 5, 7169.42    7169.42     7168.92    7168.92   -1       -1.0   -1
'IBEU50'     2019, 2, 21, 19, 17,    3262.455   3262.455    3262.455   3262.455  -1       -1.0   -1
             2019, 2, 21, 19, 17, 5, 3262.455   3262.455    3262.455   3262.455  -1       -1.0   -1
'IBDE30'     2019, 2, 21, 19, 17,    11417.15   11417.655   11416.9    11416.9   -1       -1.0   -1
             2019, 2, 21, 19, 17, 5, 11416.9    11416.905   11416.15   11416.65  -1       -1.0   -1
```

pd.DataFrame(d).transpose() gets me close, but I cannot work out how to access the nested list data as columns.

The nested lists are returned as 1xN shapes (i.e. expanding out column-wise) instead of the Nx8 shapes (i.e. expanding down row-wise) that I need.

```
            0                   1                  
'IBGB100'   RealTimeBar(...)    RealTimeBar(...)    
'IBEU50'    RealTimeBar(...)    RealTimeBar(...)    
'IBDE30'    RealTimeBar(...)    RealTimeBar(...)
```

Comment: What is `RealTimeBar`? To add to that, what type of object is `RealTimeBar`?

Comment: https://rawgit.com/erdewit/ib_insync/master/docs/html/api.html#ib_insync.objects.RealTimeBar source code https://rawgit.com/erdewit/ib_insync/master/docs/html/_modules/ib_insync/objects.html#RealTimeBar based on https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/realtime_bars.html and https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/interfaceIBApi_1_1EWrapper.html#ac23fa61ac0221a489ecd4566d1b320fe